# HP Pavilion cannot boot Windows 8; C:\ drive is in computer:///

Tags: linux, windows-8, boot, mount

I was trying out Kali Linux for the first time on my Windows 8 machine using a LiveUSB, and I somehow made my computer unable to boot my original OS.

Looking in Computer, while using Kali, I see that my `WINRE` and `Windows` drives are intact; they are stored in `computer:///`.

I suspect that it was caused by mounting/unmounting my drives incorrectly as I was  trying to access them (when I was trying to dump SAM).

What should I do to revert this? Booting Hiren's BootCD then using FixMBR was suggested, however, I am not sure this is a boot-record issue, and I don't want to mangle my system further.

Thank you!

Comment: What you haven't told us is what happans when you try to boot windows 8.  You tried another OS, it changed something (which was probably the MBR), but you haven't said what DOES happen when your booting.

Comment: @Tyson I get a screen that says "OS Boot Manager: No operating system found. Install an OS to hard disk drive." This is when I boot without the LiveUSB.

Comment: That does sound like a MBR or (Master Boot Record) problem, I'll let some else give the specific advice tho because I don't have enough specific knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

Usually the bootloader will allow you to boot multiple OS but will need both OS available in order to load either OS. 
Disclaimer- Not true in all cases i.e. Backtrack or other recovery OS

Comment: By "available," do you mean that under normal circumstances, keeping the drives in `computer:///` should allow booting into Win8?